# Is it possible to access a webpage that uses sessions on a xamarin forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a web page(.../ui/mydashboard.aspx ) which I want to display on my xamarin forms app, the problem is the web page doesn't use query parameters to provide for the users authentication details is it possible to access the web page(.../ui/mydashboard.aspx ) without having to go through the login page in my mobile app?

```
   public Dashboard ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        webView.Source = "http://dev.webapp.com/ui/mydashboard.aspx";

    }
```

Comment: if your website requires authentication then you will need to provide this information. You could get a token for the website using the user credentials for the app, this is in the case they are the same credentials if not then the authentication will be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data as the body of post request .If you don't want to let user input it , you can set a default value .

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) };

// set the params here
HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToPost), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://your.url"), content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    var responseFromServer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else {
    // handle errors
}
```